# External DNS + SRV

Tags: kubernetes, cloudflare, external-dns

I want to use [External DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns) with an SRV record. Currently, I curl the cloudflare API in order to post the node and port my pod is on. I would like ot have External DNS do this automatically. The record I attach it to is a multi A list record of all nodes on the cluster. This will not work for `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`, so I would need a better solution. External DNS seems to be the case/could save me from making a job that uses Downward API (that I'd like as a job but would then have to go about making it run on every redeployment/with the same node and at that point I'm left with a sidecar init container...which isn't bad now that I think about it)

Example: `_myrecord._tcp.myappname.myprimarydomain.net. 300 IN SRV 5 5 MYPORT MYNODE_CNAME.myprimarydomain.net`

Comment: You want to put node addresses into Cloudflare? All your nodes have public IP?

Comment: I updated the question with an example.